# HTTP Request hangs when sent from C# code

Tags: c#, rest, http, fiddler

Today I've faced an issue with the following piece of code that makes a simple POST request to my web service:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var response = new HttpClient().PostAsync("http://localhost/myservice",
            new StringContent("{ \"type\": \"confirmation\" }", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"))
            .Result;
        Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
    }
}
```

For some strange reason it hangs for a very long time. Sometimes it hangs almost forever, sometimes it returns 0 as a status code.
If I send the same request to my web service using Postman, I get 200 OK almost immediately.

Important notes:

1. It works the same with RestSharp (tried both sync and async versions):

   ```
   var client = new RestClient("http://localhost/myservice");
   var request = new RestRequest("api") { Method = Method.POST };
   request.AddJsonBody(new { type = "confirmation" });

   var response = client.Execute(request);
   ```
2. It works the same under xUnit instead of Console App (originally this code was in a unit test)
3. It's not a firewall issue. I've added the app to firewall rules. No success.
4. Tried to reboot the machine. No success.
5. Tried with IIS 10 in IIS Express. No success.

Environment: .NET 4.7, Windows 10, no custom firewalls / antimalware

Any advice will be appreciated.

**Important addition:**
It works perfectly if Fiddler is on, and stops working if Fiddler is not running.

Comment: set timeout in HTTP client and use try catch to check if any exception

Comment: and Use Fiddler to check the request and response.Its the best way to debug.

Comment: If I set a timeout, HttpClient throws `TaskCanceledException` when timout is reached.

Comment: Can you please setup fiddler and trace the req .

Comment: As you may know, Fiddler doesn't trace request made from .NET Framework to localhost, so I've replaced "localhost" with my machine's name. And, for some strange reason, all stared working just fine. Still seems strange to me.

Comment: Well I am able to trace all localhost API request and response using fiddler.DOnt know why in your case you are  unable to trace

Comment: Maybe it's your IIS binding. Have you checked your IIS website binding?

Comment: I have very common binding configuration: 80 (default one) and 443 with a developer certificate.

Comment: I've got the same issue with machine name after reboot. Happens periodically, not every time.

Comment: Investigation showed that it starts working when Fiddler is on.